# How do I know which contact I follow tweets the most?

Tags: twitter

I am following 100+ contacts and I would like to know which one of them tweets most frequently (as in "Trends" on Google Reader).

Is there a way to discover this?

Comment: Tweets frequently over what time period, the question is still vague as it stands

Answer (score 1):

[SocialBro](http://www.socialbro.com) might give you what I think you are asking for.

While their website offers a "cloud" for-pay solution, there is a Chrome Extension that is free and does most of the same features. One problem with doing the Extension route though is you must use the same computer/browser to get trending data. That is, calculating and loading the data on two computers won't have the same dataset.